# Cannot create new project Cocos 2d-x on cmd

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android

Extract Cocos 2d-x rar: C:\Users\lethi\

On cmd:
C:|Users\lethi>cocos new snackgame -p lethien.hoang.snackgames -l cpp c-d C:\Users\lethi\Desktop

Show result off: 'cocos' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable probram or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to `C:\Users\lethi\cocos2d-x\tools\cocos2d-console\bin` first, where exists `cocos.bat`, the command.

Comment: No, you should add that directory to the *PATH*.

Comment: how do that? what 's path

Comment: ok. But It show up a message box " always to use this app to open .py.

Comment: Because you haven't added `python27\python.exe` to your `PATH`. You can select it from the message box too.@J.Joe

Comment: I installed python. select it from the message box.

Comment: C:\Users\lethi\cocos2d-x\tools\cocos2d-console\bin\cocos.py new snackGame -p lethien.hoang.SnackGame -l cpp -d C:\Users\lethi\Desktop.

Comment: I don't see anything on desktop.

Comment: @J.Joe What is the output of 'cocos new.. .'?

Comment: NOthing. it just play a few second on python and exit.

Comment: @J.Joe Are you using python3? That ia not supported by cocos

Comment: Installed python-3.5.1 newest.

Comment: @J.Joe You should install python2.7

Comment: It always show always to use this app to open .py up. I don't understand. I installed 2.7.10. Now Installed 2.7.0.

Comment: After installing python2.7, you can add `C:\Python27`(might be different if you have selected other path to install python) to you PATH. @J.Joe

Comment: Then just select `Python27\python.exe`